# Classic ASP: Notify user if page is currently being viewed by another user

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, asp-classic

I have built a Help Desk system within our in house Intranet.  In general the system works fantastic.  However, I would really like to add a bit of functionality that I'm having a hard time figuring out.  What I would like to do is when a user is viewing a help ticket some sort of "lock" or "notification" is put in place such that when any other user views that page they are notified that someone is currently working on the ticket.  The issue I have is that even with my small team we often will find ourselves working on the same ticket at the same time.  It would be really helpful if when I opened a ticket I could get some sort of notification that tells me someone is already working on it so we don't double up on the work.

I currently use the following technologies for the site: Classic ASP, JavaScript, JQuery, and a SQL backup database.

I had thought about somehow coding a "locked" and "lockedBy" fields within the ticket in the SQL database such that when the ticket is opened the database is updated with "locked"=Y and "lockedBy" = .  Then when the page is closed, navigated away from, or an update to the ticket is posted the "locked" would change to "N" and "lockedBy" would change to "NULL".

I'm up for any suggestions whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com? And it is very common issue 'when and how to lock'; I'm surprised you haven't found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an ajax call on page on load and beforeunload to update the database indicating the ticket was being viewed by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar in some of my applications and store the lock status, user and date in the database.

The problem is if the user closes their browser it won't unlock.

You can solve this problem by ignoring locks with dates older than a certain time (eg. if lock date is more than 2 hours then ignore the lock).

You can improve this further by having an AJAX routine run on a JavaScript timer that regularly updates the lock date if the browser window is open. For example, every minute run an AJAX call to update the lock time, and then you can ignore locks older than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing state between all users is possible with the application object (or with a database for that matter), here is as a VBScript version:

```
function ClaimTicket(byval ticket, byval user, byref claimedby)
    on error resume next
    dim key
    key = "TICKET." & ticket
    application.lock
    if (application(key) = "") then
        application(key) = user
        ClaimTicket = true
        claimedby = user
    else
        claimedby = application(key)
    end if
    application.unlock
end
```

The lock and unlock are neccesary to prevent that some-one else is trying to claim the ticket. The function returns the name of the person that claimed the ticket. Code is not yet tested.